# findItem Method for a Linked List Inventory Program

Tags: java, linked-list, inventory

For my last assignment, I made an Inventory program, using Arrays. Our final assignment is to change the Array to a Linked List. We are not to use the LinkedList class, we are to create our own. I got my program working, but my instructor said it is only okay, but could be better. Mainly, my findItem method, in my InventoryLL class. My question is: is there a better way to go about finding an Item in my Linked List? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I have gotten 100% on each assignment so far, just trying to finishing strong, and learn as much as I can :)

```
public ItemNode findItem() 
{
    boolean found = false;
    int inputID = 0;
    ItemNode current = head;
        try{
            System.out.print("\nGreetings, please enter the ID number for item:\n");
            inputID = scannerObject.nextInt();
            scannerObject.nextLine();
        while (found != true){
         if (current.getID() == inputID){
             found = true;
             break;
            }
         current = current.getNext();
        }      
    }catch(Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println("\nERROR!");
            }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: Is your list already sorted, may be you can skip some nodes and save some valuable time

Comment: No it is not sorted. My instructor mentioned that we can, but don't have to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, is that you can't make it more efficient without making it into a (for example) skip list, which is an ordered linked list, that includes a sort of "express path".

[Wikipedia has a well written article that explains both the implementation of the list, as well as the searching of it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)

Though it might be a little bit out of scope.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Though I may not be sure we are allowed to use a skip list, seeing as we haven't gone over it in class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your code you're assuming that 'found' will eventually come true; you should be aware that it could not happen. Also, you can change the loop for avoiding using a "break", which is not very smart, altough it is not wrong.

You could too pass the value of inputID through the parameters, so your call to the function will be `findItem(0)` (or `findItem(7)` or whatever you like)

```
    public ItemNode findItem(inputID){
    boolean found = false;
for (itemNode current = head; !found; current = current.getNext()){
  if (current.getID() == inputID){
             found = true;
  }
}
if (found) {
return current;
}
else{
   System.out.println("not found"); //or some other code
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a lot of help, but the only thing is I still need to return current if nothing is found, it will just be returned as null. If any method that calls findItem gets a null value, then it displays the "not found" message. My instructor did tell me not to use break though, so thank you. But she also mentioned that I should use (!found) and (current != null) as compound conditions. So I am a little lost once again. Do you know how I could go about doing this?? Thanks in advance!